# Convert plain SQL query to SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, inner-join, mysql-connector

I am struggling to get the SQLAlchemy ORM equivalent of a plain SQL query that does a join of 3 tables based on 2 columns (Primary/Foreign key).

From MySQL workbench, the below plain SQL code works just fine with 2 tables instead of 3.

```
select * from dbase.tbl1 join dbase.tbl2
    on dbase.tbl1.user = dbase.tbl2.user and
        dbase.tbl1.domain = dbase.tbl2.domain
    where dbase.tbl1.user = "john" and
        dbase.tbl1.domain = "airline";
```

But I am unable to figure out the plain SQL or SQLAlchemy ORM code to work for 3 tables.  The plain SQL code may be something like this -

```
select * from dbase.tbl1 join dbase.tbl2
    on dbase.tbl1.user = dbase.tbl2.user and
        dbase.tbl1.domain = dbase.tbl2.domain)join dbase.tbl3
        on dbase.tbl1.user = dbase.tbl3.user and
    dbase.tbl1.domain = dbase.tbl3.domain)    
    where dbase.tbl1.user = "john" and
    dbase.tbl1.domain = "airline";
```